# Is it possible to pipe from stdin to gzip?

Tags: pipe, gzip

If I run the command `s3cmd get s3://bucket/file.gz -` I get binary output on the screen. If I try to pipe this to gzip with `s3cmd get s3://bucket/file.gz - | zcat` I get `gzip: stdin: not in gzip format`.

How can I get `zcat` to pick it's input from `stdin`?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

`gzip` and its auxilliary commands all read from STDIN by default. We can test this with a really simple test:

```
$ echo testing | gzip | zcat
testing
```

Or something more exotic to prove that wasn't a fluke:

```
$ dd if=/dev/urandom of=bigfile bs=1024 count=102400
102400+0 records in
102400+0 records out
104857600 bytes (105 MB, 100 MiB) copied, 6.42114 s, 16.3 MB/s

$ sha1sum bigfile 
25b4832d3e738e70721d86695ea7a767a3afb229  bigfile

$ cat bigfile | gzip | zcat | sha1sum 
25b4832d3e738e70721d86695ea7a767a3afb229  -
```

That suggests to me that your `s3cmd` output is dirty or malformed in some way. Try redirecting to file (rather tha providing a real filename) and then looking at the output in something like `head`. Or download it properly and compare.

Comment: I think you're right about the `s3cmd` output. I changed my approach and used `curl` instead.